# Python striping a variable everything after - dash

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code.

```
message.gateway_message_id = parsed_response['gateway_message_id'].strip()
```

After this is run `message.gateway_message_id` variable contains this:

```
18271817281-3
```

**I would now like to take `message.gateway_message_id` and strip the dash and everything after it leaving only 18271817281, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with the maxsplit parameter:

```
message.gateway_message_id.rsplit('-', 1)[0]

'18271817281-3'.rsplit('-', 1)[0] # '18271817281'
'1-2-3-4'.rsplit('-', 1)[0] # '1-2-3'
'1234'.rsplit('-', 1)[0] # '1234'
```

Comment: This is really a job for `str.partition`!

Answer (score 4):

`str.partition` (or `str.rpartition` depending on which side to strip the dash) was built for this, it will also be the fastest

```
message.gateway_message_id.rpartition('-')[0]
```

---

```
>>> text = '18271817281-3'
>>> text.rpartition('-')[0]
'18271817281'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

message.gateway_message_id='18271817281-3'
re.compile(re.escape('-')+ '.*').sub('',message.gateway_message_id)
```

out:

```
'18271817281'
```